# Ignore field in $match stage in aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, graphql

I have a GraphQL resolver which takes an argument `test` of type Boolean. Inside this resolver, I use Mongoose to carry out a MongoDB aggregation returning documents from my `users` collection based on the value of the `test` argument.

This is what my GraphQL `testUsers` resolver looks like:

```
Query: {
    testUsers: async (root, args, context) => {
        return await User.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    test: args.test
                }
            }
        ])
    }
}
```

Over here, `args.test` may be `true`, `false` or `undefined`. Handling the `true` and `false` cases is just a matter of passing it directly but I want to return all users (irrespective of the value of `test`) if `args.test` is `undefined`.

Is there a value I can pass for `test` in the `$match` stage, which will not take the `test` field into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
testUsers: async (root, args, context) => {
    let match = { test: args.test }
    if(typeof args.test === 'undefined') {
      match = {}
    }
    return await User.aggregate([
        {
            $match: match
        }
    ])
}
```

You can take a `let` variable and change its value if `args.test` is undefined

Comment: Nice solution and thanks! However, this would become quite messy if I had multiple arguments.

Comment: Nopes add as much as Field you want inside the $match

Comment: `!args.test` would be true for `false` value, which is not how it should work. I assume OP wants `typeof args.test === 'undefined'` instead.
And I agree that it would not be messy. And you can always make extra function that builds `$match` query for you.
If you are interested in performance, just don't add `$match` into aggregation if the value is undefined, because you are just slowing it down.

Comment: @TomasBruckner Thanks... Updated the answer.